# Adding list elements to empty list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to take the first element of a list created within a loop, and add it to a empty list.

Easy right? But my code is not working...

The empty list is `index`

The list I'm pulling the numbers from is `data`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ff = open("/Users/me/Documents/ff_monthly.txt", "r")
data = list(ff)

f = []
index = []

for i in range (1, len(data)):

    t = data[i].split()
    index.append(int(t[0]))

    for j in range(1, 5):

        k = float(t[j])
        f.append(k / 100)

n = len(f)

f1 = np.reshape(f,[n / 4, 4])

ff = pd.DataFrame(f1, index= index, columns = ['Mkt_Rf','SMB','HML','Rf'])
ff.to_pickle("ffMonthly.pickle")
print ff.head()
```

When I create the list `t` in the loop, I've checked to see if it is being created correctly.

```
len(t) =   5

print t[0] =  192607

print t = ['192607', '2.95', '-2.54', '-2.65', '0.22']
```

The code:

```
index.append(t[0])
```

It should add the 1st element of the list `t` to `index` ... correct?

However, I get this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I missing here?

Edit:

Posted the entire code above.

Here are the first few rows of "ff_monthly.txt"

```
          Mkt-RF   SMB     HML     RF
192607    2.95   -2.54   -2.65    0.22
192608    2.64   -1.22    4.25    0.25
192609    0.37   -1.21   -0.39    0.23
192610   -3.24   -0.09    0.26    0.32
192611    2.55   -0.15   -0.54    0.31
192612    2.62   -0.13   -0.08    0.28
```

Comment: Are you sure `index.append(t[0])` is the line causing the error?

Comment: The code, as written, has syntax errors, making it hard to re-create what your code does when it executes.

Comment: line 15, in <module>
    index.append(int(t[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Unless I'm reading that wrong :/

Comment: I am sure enough to say that something you state cannot be true.  If the `print t` really prints a list with several entries (and if thus `t` is a list of several entries) then the `index.append(t[0])` *cannot* raise an `IndexError`.  So please try to find out what you got wrong here.  If you are very sure that you've got everything right (in spite of my conclusion), then please build a minimal *complete* example showing the problem and post that here, so that other people can reproduce it.

Comment: waht does data contain?

Comment: I'll post the entire code above

Comment: You've shown the first lines of the input file, but are you sure that all the `t` lists are gonna have 5 elements?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is an empty line in your txt file.

Because "".split() will return an empty list which will fail the t[0]

Answer (score 0):

Quick and uggly:

```
for i in range (1, len(data)):
   t = data[i].split()
   if t:
       index.append(int(t[0]))
       for j in range(1, 5):
          k = float(t[j])
          f.append(k / 100)
```

Reason:

You have empty lines at the end of the file. Reproduced locally.